# Enabling and Disabling a Textfield, depending on the Dropdown (Select) result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-hook-form

I have been having trouble in enabling and disabling a textfield depending on the result of the dropdown.
in the code below when i click **others** from purposes i want the textfield to enabled. else if not equal to others it will remain disabled.

---

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Typography, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";

const offices = [
  { label: "Building Management Office", value: "Building Management Office" },
  {
    label: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
    value: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
  },
  {
    label: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
    value: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
  },
];

const purposes = [
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
  },
  { label: "Organization Purposes", value: "Organization Purposes" },
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
  },
  { label: "Special Events", value: "Special Events" },
  { label: "Others", value: "Others" },
];

const teachers = [
  "Ms Roselle Wednesday Gardon",
  "Mr Jojo Castillo",
  "Mr John Patrick Lite",
  "Mr Patrick Star",
];

const Test_Form = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, setValue, watch, register } = useForm();

  const selectedPurpose = watch("purposes");
  console.log(selectedPurpose);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue("specificPurpose", ""); // Clear the specificPurpose when purpose changes
  }, [selectedPurpose]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="borrowing-transaction">
        <Typography>Borrowing Information</Typography>
        <div className="office">
          <Typography>Office</Typography>
          <Controller
            name="offices"
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} options={offices} />}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="purposes">
          <Typography>Purpose</Typography>
          <Controller
            name="purposes"
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} options={purposes} />}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="specific-purpose">
          <Typography>Specific Purpose</Typography>
          <TextField
            label="Enter Specific Purpose"
            variant="filled"
            fullWidth
            style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            disabled={selectedPurpose === "Others" ? false : true}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Test_Form;
```

I tried using setValue, but it doesn't work here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Typography, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";

const offices = [
  { label: "Building Management Office", value: "Building Management Office" },
  {
    label: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
    value: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
  },
  {
    label: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
    value: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
  },
];

const purposes = [
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
  },
  { label: "Organization Purposes", value: "Organization Purposes" },
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
  },
  { label: "Special Events", value: "Special Events" },
  { label: "Others", value: "Others" },
];

const teachers = [
  "Ms Roselle Wednesday Gardon",
  "Mr Jojo Castillo",
  "Mr John Patrick Lite",
  "Mr Patrick Star",
];

const Test_Form = () => {
  const { control, handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm();

  const selectedPurpose = watch("purposes");
  console.log(selectedPurpose);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue("specificPurpose", ""); // Clear the specificPurpose when purpose changes
  }, [selectedPurpose]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="borrowing-transaction">
        <Typography>Borrowing Information</Typography>
        <div className="office">
          <Typography>Office</Typography>
          <Controller
            name="offices"
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} options={offices} />}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="purposes">
          <Typography>Purpose</Typography>
          <Controller
            name="purposes"
            control={control}
            defaultValue=""
            render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} options={purposes} />}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="specific-purpose">
          <Typography>Specific Purpose</Typography>
          <TextField
            label="Enter Specific Purpose"
            variant="filled"
            fullWidth
            style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            disabled={selectedPurpose === "Others" ? false : true}
            {...control("specificPurpose")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Test_Form;
```

I also tried but it doesn't work

```
disabled={selectedPurpose === "Others" ? false : true}
```

Comment: You can't have `selectedPurpose` as a dependency to your useEffect cuz it creates an infinite loop.  Eliminate the `useEffect` and set the value directly onChange or some similar event.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but missed a few pieces.

First off, the main issue is the option or the value being selected is an object so you cannot directly compare `selected === 'Others'` because it will always be false (I added a console log in the use effect to show this).

Second, if you ever want to clear a field or reset to default values or even clear the entire form, you should always use react-hook-form `reset()` which you can pass params to tell it which ones to keep or reset or reset all etc. For this example, you can `reset({selectedPurpose:''})` so, replace your `setvalue()` in the use effect with this! [You can check out the documentation here](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/reset)

Third, you cannot always use `{...field}` to spread props onto an input field, especially when it is from a library that isn't prime react or one that supports the same props (which react-select does not).

Lastly the InputText at the end.. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `...control` spread but I added an example with and without a controller (I suggest using the controller).

So in conclusion instead of spreading all hook form fields, you have to explicitly give desired and required props(when using react-select) and remember when using react-select, the selected item will always be of type {label:string, value:string} so to use the result you must do something like `result?.label` or `result?.value`

Below are two working examples, first in TS and second in JS:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./App.css";
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const offices = [
  { label: "Building Management Office", value: "Building Management Office" },
  {
    label: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
    value: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
  },
  {
    label: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
    value: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
  },
];

const purposes = [
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
  },
  { label: "Organization Purposes", value: "Organization Purposes" },
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
  },
  { label: "Special Events", value: "Special Events" },
  { label: "Others", value: "Others" },
];

interface InputFormFields {
  selectedOffice: { label: string; value: string };
  selectedPurpose: { label: string; value: string };
  specificPurposeInputText: string;
}
//typescript
function App() {
  const { control, watch, handleSubmit } = useForm<InputFormFields>();
  const selectedPurpose = watch("selectedPurpose");

  const onSubmit = (data: InputFormFields) => {
    console.log("submit hit with data:", data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selected purpose changed to:", selectedPurpose);
  }, [selectedPurpose]);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", color: "white" }}>
      <h1>Test Screen</h1>
      <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h5>hook form + react-select example</h5>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

            <div style={{ color: "black" }}>

              <Controller
                name="selectedOffice"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Select
                    options={offices}
                    ref={field.ref}
                    value={offices.find((c) => c.value === field.value.value)}
                    onChange={field.onChange}
                  />
                )}
              />

              <Controller
                name="selectedPurpose"
                control={control}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <Select
                    options={purposes}
                    ref={field.ref}
                    value={offices.find((c) => c.value === field.value.value)}
                    onChange={field.onChange}
                  />
                )}
              />

              <TextField
                label="Enter Specific Purpose"
                variant="filled"
                fullWidth
                style={{
                  backgroundColor:
                    selectedPurpose.value === "Others" ? "red" : "white",
                }}
                disabled={selectedPurpose.value === "Others" ? false : true}
              />
              {/*
              Or if you want it to be a part of the control (suggested) use this!!
               <Controller
                control={control}
                name="specificPurposeInputText"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <TextField
                    label="Enter Specific Purpose"
                    variant="filled"
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={field.onChange}
                    fullWidth
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor:
                        selectedPurpose.value === "Others" ? "red" : "white",
                    }}
                    disabled={selectedPurpose.value === "Others" ? false : true}
                  />
                )}
              /> */}
            </div>
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "black", color: "white" }}>
              <Button type="submit">SUBMIT</Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Here is the JSX version:**

```
import { Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";
//constants
const offices = [
  { label: "Building Management Office", value: "Building Management Office" },
  {
    label: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
    value: "Information Technology and Resource Office",
  },
  {
    label: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
    value: "Engineering and Science Laboratory Office",
  },
];
const purposes = [
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Assignment & Activities",
  },
  { label: "Organization Purposes", value: "Organization Purposes" },
  {
    label: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
    value: "Academic Purposes - Midterms & Finals",
  },
  { label: "Special Events", value: "Special Events" },
  { label: "Others", value: "Others" },
];
//javascript version
export const ExampleInJs = () => {
  const { control, watch, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
  const selectedPurpose = watch("selectedPurpose");
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("onSubmit hit with data: ", data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selected purpose changed to:", selectedPurpose);
    if (selectedPurpose?.value && selectedPurpose.value === "Others") {
      console.log("Others option hit, disabling submit");
      reset({specificPurposeInputText:''});
    }
  }, [selectedPurpose]);
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <h5>hook form + react-select example</h5>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div style={{ color: "black" }}>
            <Controller
              name="selectedOffice"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Select
                  options={offices}
                  ref={field.ref}
                  value={offices.find((c) => c.value === field.value)}
                  onChange={field.onChange}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Controller
              name="selectedPurpose"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <Select
                  options={purposes}
                  ref={field.ref}
                  value={offices.find((c) => c.value === field.value)}
                  onChange={field.onChange}
                />
              )}
            />             
            <Controller
                control={control}
                name="specificPurposeInputText"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <TextField
                    label="Enter Specific Purpose"
                    variant="filled"
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={field.onChange}
                    fullWidth
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor:
                        selectedPurpose?.value === "Others" ? "red" : "white",
                    }}
                    disabled={ selectedPurpose?.value === "Others" ? false : true}
                  />
                )}
              /> 
          </div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "black", color: "white" }}>
            <Button type="submit">SUBMIT</Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: sorry but i forgot to say i am currently using jsx, not typescript i can't use interface.  is const the counterpart of interface? sorry again because i just started react

interface InputFormFields {
  selectedOffice: { label: string; value: string };
  selectedPurpose: { label: string; value: string };
  specificPurposeInputText: string;
}

Comment: no worries, ill update my answer with a jsx version shortly.

Comment: I added a JSX version, you can directly copy and paste this into a component folder and import it anywhere. The last input has been left how you made it but underneath I commented code that is the same exact input but wrapped in a controller so it can be used by hook form and will be added to data during the onSubmit.

Comment: oh and I also added a background color change to red when 'Others' / disabled is true for extra visualization so you can clearly see everything is updating and working as it should.